# Switch case help in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++

**The question is**

```
int i = 6, x = 11;

switch(i % 3 ? 0 : 1)
{
  case 0:  x /=2;  break;
  case 1:  x +=3; 
  case 2:  x *=4;
}
cout << "x = " << x;
```

So the answer i should be getting is x=5, however, from the answer script it said it should be x= 56.
Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Both statements:

```
x +=3;
```

and

```
x *=4;
```

are executed. This is why (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) for conditional operator reference and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) for the switch statement).

In the expression

```
i % 3 ? 0 : 1
```

`i % 3` is the condition. Being an integer value, it's considered false if equal to zero, true otherwise. In your case `i` has value 6, thus `i % 3` is 0, thus the condition is false and the value after the `:` is taken to be evaluated in the `switch` statement.

The value after the `:` is `1`, so the code jumps to `case 1` and executes `x += 3`. Now `x` is **11+3=14**.

But there is no `break` statement before `case 2`, so the execution simply goes on with `x *= 4` and `x` becomes **14*4=56**.